# Django redirects missing out WSGIScriptAlias part of url

Tags: django, url, redirect, mod-wsgi

I have a django application set up using mainly the admin interface with a few of my own views. Everything is working corrctly on the devlopment server on my local machine.

However on the production server, using Apache, and mod_wsgi, it is messing up the URLs when I issue a redirect statement in one of my views. Instead of going to

```
     www.hostname.com/wsgi/django/admin/myapp/myform.html
```

it goes to

```
     www.hostname.com/admin/myapp/myform.html
```

Apache doesn't recognise anything under an admin folder, so I get an error.

So in my apache configuration I have the following, so that anything under wsgi/django gets sent to my app:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/django /project/production/public/wsgi/django_eclipse/myapp.wsgi
```

In my problematic view I have the following:

```
return redirect('/admin/sequencing/load_flowcell?' + params )
```

I can make this work, if I change the redirect to include the '/wsgi/django' part, but this means I can't keep the one on my development server the same. Is there a way in Django settings, or http.conf to set this so that my redirect automatically includes this part of the URL?

Comment: Post your WSGI script file so we can make sure that you haven't done something in their to muck up how SCRIPT_NAME is passed into the application. There are various wrong scripts out there on blogs which would be wrong to use when mounting at a sub URL.

Comment: any chance of marking an answer as accepted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: REAL FIX

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, get_script_prefix
....
#only of you absolutely HAVE to have a hardcoded url
return redirect(get_script_prefix()+'admin/sequencing/load_flowcell?'+params )
#better!
return redirect(reverse('admin:index')+sequencing/load_flowcell?'+params )
```

CAVEAT:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#basic-configuration

```
<Location "/mysite/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonOption django.root /mysite     <---- Make sure you have this
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

Comment: Which is irrelevant, as the OP is clearly (and correctly) using mod_wsgi not mod_python.

Comment: The point is that this setting enables the app to append that prefix. This is how i read the question, as an answer to the "no prefix" problem. did not notice no prefix in redirect.

Comment: Thanks, Django is a pretty comprehensive framework, so isn't always easy to find what part you should be using in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Django can use the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) to generate correct urls when reversing -- if you change the `domain` field in the `Site` row associated with your site (as indicated by `SITE_ID` in your `settings.py`) to `http://www.hostname.com/wsgi/admin`, then everything should work fine.

(There may also be a few places where you have plain urls, e.g. the `LOGIN_URL` or `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` settings that you should make sure include the `/wsgi/admin` part.)

Comment: Many thanks, added SITE_ID to the settings file, then used the reverse('admin:index') + in my redirect statement. I can probably clean up a few more workarounds now.

Comment: OK, it wasn't the SITE ID variable in settings.py, as that ended up breaking a lot of stuff, as it is supposed to be an integer. Using reverse('admin:index') seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's redirecting to exactly the URL that you told it to.

This is why you should never hard-code URLs anywhere in Django. If you used the URL-reversing functionality, it would *automatically* add the WSGI prefix - it knows about it already, and takes it into account when you use the `{% url %}` tag or the `reverse()` function.

Give the URL a name in your urls.py, and use that in the call to redirect rather than the URL, and all should work fine. No need for more settings.

Comment: If you are going to down vote something please say why. What Daniel says is correct to the extent that when you mount at a sub URL of the web server, you must use the correct means in Django for reversing URLs. There are a few exceptions to this rule but the concept of what Daniel is correct and shouldn't be dimissed without saying why what he has said is not applicable.

Comment: I did try with relative urls, but the error it gave implied that redirect expected a hard coded URL.